# How do I count categories beginning with specific letters, but still include letters with '0'

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My query gives me the number of categories that begin with each letter

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(headings.heading,1,1) AS first_letter, COUNT(*) AS cat_count
FROM TABLE a
        INNER JOIN headings
        ON a.Heading=headings.heading 
  GROUP BY first_letter
```

Gives me:

```
A - 5
B - 4
C - 4
D - 2
F - 10
G - 9
```

and so on until Z

But I also want the result to contain letters that have a 0 count. `eg. E - 0` I'm guessing this could be tricky with SQL because I'm trying to get something that doesn't exist. Will I have to do this in PHP? And if so, any ideas how I might do this?

Comment: Create a dummy table with all possible starts, LEFT JOIN the rest on that.

Comment: The above comment is the answer.

Comment: @Jithin Shaji: While doing Left Join the value for the data missing will be null. So you must handle it by using IsNull function.

Comment: Yes, use ISNULL() function around the count column.

Comment: @Wrikken By "dummy table" do you mean create a table in the database with one column with 26 rows, one for each letter of the alphabet?

Comment: @Metzed: yes, or any other first characters you might imagine being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a table with only one field which contains all possible result (in your case a-z) then left outer join from this table to your data..

e.g. FirstLetters table:

```
Letter
------
A
B
C
..
Y
Z
```

Then your query would become something like:

```
SELECT letter as first_letter, COUNT(a.heading) AS cat_count
FROM 
    FirstLetters l
    left outer join
    TABLE a
    ON left(a.Heading,1)=l.letter 
GROUP BY letter
```

sorry if this si not 100% correct syntax.. not used mysql recently

Answer (score 0):

This just might work for you:

```
WITH Departments AS (
SELECT SUBSTRING(D.Name,1,1) AS First_Letter, COUNT(*) AS name_count
FROM HumanResources.Department D
Group BY SUBSTRING(D.Name,1,1))

SELECT Letter, ISNULL(D.name_count,0)
FROM Letters L
LEFT JOIN Departments D ON L.Letter = D.First_letter
```

Basically with this I am creating a CTE with the count of letters using your substring statement and comparing that to my letters table. If the letter is not found in the department table it will return 0. Hope this helps! For the letters table I just created a simple table with one column and each letter of the alphabet as the values.